# How to display a hosted url in a particular div by onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, tabs

I am trying to display a hosted url application in a particular div though an onclick on the anchor and this should open in same tab.

**Code in Context**

```
 <div class="container-fluid text-center col-md-12 collapse out" id="orange" style="height: 30px; background-color: orange">

 <a type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnk" href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return go(this);">Google</a>

</div>
```

**Function used for the above**

```
function go(obj) {
            var page = obj.href;
            document.getElementById('g2g').innerHTML = '<object data="' + page + '" type="text/html"><embed src="' + page + '" type="text/html" /></object>';
            return false;
        }
    });

    function setURL(url) {
        document.getElementById('g2g').src = url;
    }
```

This **Google link needs to open in the following div**

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center col-md-12" id="g2g">
        <div class="row content">


                    <div id="map" class="fill" style="z-index: 100;">
                    </div>


        </div>

    </div>
```

Currently it opens in same tab but not in that particular div expected. Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: why you are not using iframes?

Comment: I tried using iframe but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: <iframe id="iframeId" src="#map" ></iframe>
<input type="button" value="click here!" onclick="$('#iframeId').attr('src', 'http://www.google.com')"/>

Comment: it will work fine right.. also give some width and height properties for iframe

Comment: its working ....but one more problem is which is not coming to the div i expected...